# Gitlab : How to Ignore Merge Conflicts for Specific Files?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a problem with resolving merge conflicts in my Gitlab repo.

There are several branches, i.e. `main`, `dev` and `feature_1`.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: node

default:
  tags:
    - node

stages:
  - build

build-job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - dev
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
```

I want to make `only` attribute unique for each branch:

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml for DEV branch

build-job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - dev
```

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml for MAIN branch

build-job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - main
```

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml for FEATURE_1 branch

build-job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - dev
```

---

Unfortunately, setting Gitlab `${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}` variable for `only` attribute will not work because it is invalid syntax and CI/CD pipeline will throw an error. Besides everything it's a not the solution since `feature_1` branch should not trigger any job.

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml for all branches

build-job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
# Gitlab will trigger pipeline for feature_1 branch in theory
```

---

Locally, it works fine. I've already set up `.gitattributes` to ignore conflicts for `.gitlab-ci.yml` file on merge. [This link](https://gist.github.com/tmaybe/4c9d94712711229cd506) was helpful for me.

```
# .gitattributes

.gitlab-ci.yml merge=ours
```

```
# git config merge.ours.driver true
# cat .git/config

[merge "ours"]
    driver = true
```

So if I merge branches locally, `.gitlab-ci.yml` has different versions for each branch without an issue.

How to implement the same behaviour for remote branches in Gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in `only` keyword, but the way you were attempting it was wrong thus why GitLab complains about an error in the CI/CD file.

Use it like this instead:

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"
```

The documentation that shows how to use it can be seen [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariables--exceptvariables)